# Majorate $\frac{x}{\log(1-x)}$ and its derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

How to find an upperbound for 
$$f(x) = \frac{x}{\log(1-x)}$$
And its derivatives at any order, on the interval $(-1, 1)$ ?

I can find one easily for a given order, but I can't find any general method.

Comment: what kind of $log(.)$ is it?

Comment: $\ln$ - base $e$